# Composable Storefront (Spartacus) version 5 and TELCO

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I'm helping the Spartacus upgrade to version 5.x, but the store is using the Telco library (tua-sap). We were able to upgrade the Composable Storefront to version 5 but we couldn't figure out how to upgrade the **spa-tua** version too and even if it is necessary. We didn't understand if the Telco is incorporated inside the Composable Storefront or if there is another separate TUA library and where is it, or if we must use version 4.x for the **TUA** side by side with the Composable Storefront 5. The repository for the new version seems to not have any tua-spa library. Can anyone provide the steps to upgrade the TELCO to version 5, clearer than the official documentation?